# RNN model running out of memory in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I implemented a Sequence to Sequence model using the rnn.rnn helper in TensorFlow.

```
with tf.variable_scope("rnn") as scope, tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(4096)
    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * 2)

    _, cell = rnn.rnn(lstm, input_vectors, dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    lstm_outputs, _ = rnn.rnn(lstm, output_vectors, initial_state=cell)
```

The model is running out of memory on a Titan X with 16 GB of memory while allocating gradients for the LSTM cells:

```
W tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc:158] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8192,16384]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x2b42f00 Compute status: Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8192,16384]
     [[Node: gradients/rnn/RNN/MultiRNNCell_1/Cell0/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](rnn/RNN/MultiRNNCell_1/Cell0/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/concat, gradients/rnn/RNN/MultiRNNCell_1/Cell0/BasicLSTMCell/add_grad/tuple/control_dependency)]]
```

If I reduce the length of the input and output sequences to 4 or less the model runs without a problem.

This indicates to me that TF is trying to allocate the gradients for all time steps at the same time. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `tf.gradients` as well as the `minimize` method of the optimizers allow you to set parameter called `aggregation_method`. The default value is `ADD_N`. This method constructs the graph in such a way that all gradients need to be computed at the same time.

There are two other undocumented methods called  `tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_TREE` and  `tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N`, which do not have this requirement.